# How to parse number to text

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

Let's say i have an X value representing the Runtime patch output, it is a number which is the time elapsed since the start of the effect. How can i show that X value into a 2d text?

I tried to use Unpack patch and sending the value to a script and then setting the text what nothing worked for me

I excpect the text to show the Number value while running the effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/reactivemodule.scalarsignal) you can use **ScalarSignal format** method:

```
const Patches = require('Patches');

const numberFormat = 'Time: {0}';
const number = Patches.getScalarValue('number');

Patches.setStringValue('value', number.format(numberFormat));
```

Create proper to & from script values:

[image: From & to script values]

And link proper nodes in patch editor:

[image]