# Parsing scalar number to text in Spark AR

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to link a device motion value to a 2D Text element, so that the rotation Y value will appear as text in my scene.

I've been trying to implement a solution described in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640158/how-to-parse-number-to-text), with no luck. Apparently since v85 was released in March 2020 there have been some changes to how scripting works in Spark AR.

This is the code I used in my project:

```
const Patches = require('Patches');

const numberFormat = 'Time: {0}';
const number = Patches.getScalarValue('number');

Patches.setStringValue('value', number.format(numberFormat));
```

[This is what my script looks like in the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5KFS.png)

[Patch I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxGok.png)

[My To and From script values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ6lJ.png)

If anyone knows why the script is not working, please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The API changed to Promise based. This means that Patches.getScalarValue() will give you a Promise.
This script should work:

```js
const Patches = require('Patches');

// enable async/await 
(async () => {
const numberFormat = 'Time: {0}';
const number = await Patches.getScalarValue('number');

Patches.setStringValue('value', number.format(numberFormat));

})()
```

Also you didn't provide the error from SparkAR Studio.